# How to build an expert system similar to ES-Builder Web

Tags: expert-systems

I made a simple expert system using [ES-Builder](https://www.mcgoo.com.au/html/es-builder.php). Please click the [link](http://www.mcgoo.com.au/esbuilder/viewer/viewES.php?es=f6269594b3f20cd14716c7c1fc6f60e8) to view it. ES-Builder is a web-based **expert system shell**. There is a tree-based knowledge representation. In ES builder, User Interfaces are also automatically designed. They generate a link as I have shared above and anyone can access it and can use it.

But when I try other ES shells such as [JESS](https://synotix.home.xs4all.nl/robbieng/docs/jess43doc.html), [CLIPS](https://www.science.gov/topicpages/c/clips+expert+system.html) & [PyKE](http://pyke.sourceforge.net/), I only noticed that there we have to write facts and rules and the program is run on command line upon consulting the Expert System. There is no UI like in ES-Builder.

My question is, is there any way to build UI to the expert systems created by CLIPS/JESS? Or else should I create a web application using another framework like Spring, DotNet, and integrate it with the knowledge base created with CLIPS/JESS?

(I am a bit confused, because according to what I have learned: if we use an expert system shell then we need not program it using languages (such as Prolog). Because the User Interfaces and Inference Engine is already there. What we are remained to do is just to build the knowledge base. Similar to ES builder UI is auto built.)

Thank you very much for the support! If the question is confusing, I am happy to modify it in a more understandable manner.

Comment: Hello. It may be a good idea to provide the link to JESS and CLIPS. Personally, I had never heard of the term "ES shell", but I am also far from an expert in ES. So, it may be a good idea to tell us what you learned about ES shells. Having said that, this question seems to be about specific software, so I am afraid it's off-topic. However, given that it's about ES and no other place probably covers this topic, I will leave it open for now.

Comment: @nbro Thank you for your concern. Actually, ES shells are developed with the purpose of building expert systems without the knowledge of a specific programming language. This is the definition I learned from my professor. ES builder perfectly matches the definition. but in my research, I found there are many others like CLIPS, JESS, PyKE where programming has to be done manually. This is contradictory to what I have learned. That is why I'm seeking help from an expert in this community. I will provide more information and necessary references in my question ASAP.

Comment: @PawaraSiriwardhane did you find a proper solution to this question? I'm having the same exact problem and ES builder seems to be the feasible solution to get a decent UI without too much ground work.

Answer (score 0):

Most old school Expert System tools are text based and based on If/Then rules going forwards or backwards (chaining)

Some have graphical front ends (such as VisiRule (https://www.visirule.co.uk/), XpertRule, etc)

Some have now repositioned themselves as Business Rules tools and most of these have GUIs (InRule, Actico etc)